# Align code line numbers with CSS

Tags: css, pre, css-counter

I'm trying to insert line numbers in code snippets on my website (https://qscintilla.com/custom-lexer-example/), using a pure CSS approach (no javascript):

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot above, I'm building my website in Wordpress. I use the "Additional CSS" feature from the latest Wordpress version to insert custom CSS. Here is my custom CSS:

```
pre{
    counter-reset: line;
}
code{
    counter-increment: line;
}
code:before{
    content: counter(line);
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    color: #888;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

It works pretty good, when I'm inserting code snippets in my HTML like so:

```
<pre>
<code> This is my first codeline </code>
<code> This is my second codeline </code>
<code> This is my third codeline </code>
<code> This is my fourth codeline </code>
</pre>
```

Unfortunately, the line numbers don't get aligned properly when the code line reaches double digits. Let's zoom in on the problem:

[image]

Of course, the same problem arises when the code line jumps from double to triple digits

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a pure CSS solution, there is only one way: use a fixed-width solution, i.e. explicitly declare a width on the `::before` pseudo-element. However, this approach is never future-proof as you will have to account for scenarios where the counter might run into 3, 4, or more digits.

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: line;
}

code {
  counter-increment: line;
}

code::before {
  content: counter(line);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em; /* Fixed width */
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #888;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
<code>Code</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you @Terry! This is indeed not future-proof, but it is good enough for my case. By the way, why the double `::` instead of the single `:`?

Comment: That's actually the updated convention (CSS3) for pseudo element vs selectors. Pseudo elements should have double colon `::` (e.g. `::before` and `::after`), while pseudo selectors should have only one (e.g. `:hover`, `:focus`, `:valid`). Note that internet explorer 7 and 8 will not work with `::before`, but will with `:before`.

Comment: On a side note, if you really want a future proof solution there is no other way but to alter your DOM. GitHub, for example, uses table layout to display line numbers and code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with CSS Grid. The width of line numbers increases dynamically so you wouldn't get any error in future with big numbers. Take a look at below;

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: line 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1em;
  gap: 0.3em;
}

.line-number {
  text-align: right;
}

.line-number::before {
  counter-increment: line;
  content: counter(line);
  white-space: pre;
  color: #888;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `ol` instead of `pre`, offering a **flexible**-width solution.

```css
li::marker {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
<li>Code
</ol>
```

However, `::marker` styling seems limited (`list-style-type`). E.g. removing the period or `vertical-align: super` seems to needs other workarounds (back to `li:before` and `counter`).

Bonus: `<li>` also does not need the closing tag `</li>` (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags), which saves typing.